# Hexacopter Simulation

Tags: simulation, pid, dynamics, multi-rotor, flight-controller

I am doing a project to simulate a hexacopter with the mathematical model and its dynamics with PID. I've got the theoretical knowledge but am stuck on simulation. Would any of you happen to have any tips or ideas on where to start, websites, or blog posts to refer to? I would appreciate any help.